# refining flow union type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Please see the code below. I have to do two casting to avoid any flow error. If I use the commented out lines instead, it complains.

[playground](http://Hi,%20%20Following%20code%20give%20flowtype%20error,%20which%20is%20bit%20hard%20to%20decipher%20%20[demo][1]%20%20%20%20%20%20/*%20@flow%20*/%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20import%20*%20as%20React%20from%20%22react%22;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%20Action%20=%20React.Node%20%7C%20%7B%20label:%20string,%20path?:%20string,%20query?:%20Array%3Cstring%3E%20%7D;%20%20%20%20%20type%20ActionButtonProp%20=%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20actions:%20Array%3CAction%3E,%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20export%20default%20function%20ActionButton(%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20actions%20=%20[],%20%20%20%20%20%7D:%20ActionButtonProp)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20items%20=%20actions.map((item,%20idx)%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(React.isValidElement(item))%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20key:%20idx.toString(),%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%3Cspan%20/%3E;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%3Cdiv%3Eitems%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20error%20--%20%20%20%20%20%20[LIB]%20static/v0.54.1/flowlib/react.js:159:%20declare%20type%20React$Element%3C%20ElementType:%20React$ElementType%3E%20=%20%7B%7C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20property%20%60key%60.%20Property%20not%20found%20in%20%20%20%20%2015:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20object%20type%20%20%20%20%20[LIB]%20static/v0.54.1/flowlib/react.js:159:%20declare%20type%20React$Element%3C%20ElementType:%20React$ElementType%3E%20=%20%7B%7C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20property%20%60props%60.%20Property%20not%20found%20in%20%20%20%20%2015:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20object%20type%20%20%20%20%20[LIB]%20static/v0.54.1/flowlib/react.js:159:%20declare%20type%20React$Element%3C%20ElementType:%20React$ElementType%3E%20=%20%7B%7C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20property%20%60ref%60.%20Property%20not%20found%20in%20%20%20%20%2015:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20object%20type%20%20%20%20%20[LIB]%20static/v0.54.1/flowlib/react.js:159:%20declare%20type%20React$Element%3C%20ElementType:%20React$ElementType%3E%20=%20%7B%7C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20property%20%60type%60.%20Property%20not%20found%20in%20%20%20%20%2015:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20object%20type%20%20%20%20%2015:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20$Iterable.%20Inexact%20type%20is%20incompatible%20with%20exact%20type%20%20%20%20%2015:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20exact%20type:%20object%20type%20%20%20%20%2015:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20boolean.%20Inexact%20type%20is%20incompatible%20with%20exact%20type%20%20%20%20%2015:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20exact%20type:%20object%20type%20%20%20%20%2015:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20null.%20Inexact%20type%20is%20incompatible%20with%20exact%20type%20%20%20%20%2015:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20exact%20type:%20object%20type%20%20%20%20%2015:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20number.%20Inexact%20type%20is%20incompatible%20with%20exact%20type%20%20%20%20%2015:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20exact%20type:%20object%20type%20%20%20%20%2015:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20object%20type.%20Inexact%20type%20is%20incompatible%20with%20exact%20type%20%20%20%20%2015:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20exact%20type:%20object%20type%20%20%20%20%2015:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20string.%20Inexact%20type%20is%20incompatible%20with%20exact%20type%20%20%20%20%2015:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20exact%20type:%20object%20type%20%20%20%20%2015:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20undefined.%20Inexact%20type%20is%20incompatible%20with%20exact%20type%20%20%20%20%2015:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20React.cloneElement(item,%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%20exact%20type:%20object%20type%20%20%20%20%201:1%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBdkwBDAZzACUBTUgY2KnzizACJ87H2BudQgE8cNMAEFGGOADswAXmrdCAOgBycACaiAPmADeYGKQBGNGAC4w5QvgzSA5gBowOUoQAWAfkvXbD5wCOAK40%20ILe4vj4pIIAPL529gB8YAC%20-EIi4pIyAEJBhIQyAAosOPL6qGDVZDnS5JZiUTGxEoRS0kmOqKnoNAAeeERgWlCkQTBMQdJ12e15BUXSABR6VbXz9RUA2gC63amNdfmFJWUAlJXV9DLWYBiENFiUCgyb5MpYpDjLyw9PzgwGn6lzkKTWNXuUDAy1ob2UGHIADVSDAgQBRGBPGjSQh-R5Yc6XCGQsBcQhBfCyOGMZT0eDSGiY7G4-EAq6k6oAaxogksQP6yiKAGUbIlludupzUud%20JDeutquTKbJ4q5ZMAknK0rL0EqaBSqWBYhoMAA3JL-Z6xYCmi09VBAA)

```
/* @flow */

import * as React from "react";

type ConfObj = { label: string };
type Conf = React.Node | ConfObj;
type MyComponentProp = {
    confs: Array<Conf>,
}

export default function MyComponent({
  confs = [],
}: MyComponentProp) {
  const items = confs.map((item, idx) => {
    if (React.isValidElement(item)) {
      // return React.cloneElement(item, {
      return React.cloneElement(((item: any): React.Element<*>), {
        key: idx.toString(),
      });
    }

   const item2 = ((item: any): ConfObj);
   return <span>{item2.label}</span>;
   // return <span>{item.label}</span>;
  });

  return <div>items</div>
}
```

Is there a better way to do this to avoid the casting. Is there a better way to write `isValidElement`, so flow can deduce the type once the if condition matches. For example, if it is a valid react element, why do I need to cast it? or if it not, why accessing `label` gives error?

Answer (score 0):

An `item` is of type `Conf` (which is `Node | ConfObj`)
When you enter the `if` statement, `flow` doesn't know for sure that `item` is a valid `Element<*>` (this could be known by `flow` I think tho), so you have to explicitly typecast it.

The `<span>{item.label}</span>` has the same problem. You also have to explicitly typecast it to a `ConfObj`, because a `Node` doesn't have a `label` attribute.